# How to resolve the failed import analysis error when using react Context with ionic react v7 and vite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, vite, react-context

I faced a challenge using the react Context in the new ionic react v7. I get this error in the screen and in the console:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
C:/Users/Getty/Documents/GitHub/quest-ionic-7/src/context/AuthContext.js:291:1
233|        {children}
234|      </UserContext.Provider>;
235|  };
   |   ^
236|  _s(AuthContextProvider, "UoGSIHopmDvLPTUYClKBZu0bFSs=");
237|  _c = AuthContextProvider;
    at formatError (file:///C:/Users/Getty/Documents/GitHub/quest-ionic-7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:42645:46)
    at TransformContext.error (file:///C:/Users/Getty/Documents/GitHub/quest-ionic-7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:42641:19)
    at TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/Users/Getty/Documents/GitHub/quest-ionic-7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:40447:22)
    at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/Getty/Documents/GitHub/quest-ionic-7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:42919:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/Users/Getty/Documents/GitHub/quest-ionic-7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:53385:29
Click outside or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.
```

I simply copied and pasted code from an app I did with ionic v6 so i expected no problems, this seems to comes from the vite plugin.
I tried converting the context file to a jsx file from a js file. When I do that I get error when importing the context into modules or even the App.tsx file. It tells me that it was not exported even though I clearly exported it.

This is the AuthContext.js code

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  updatePassword,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  updateProfile,
  updateEmail,
  reauthenticateWithCredential,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, setDoc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from "../../firebase";
import { en, fr } from "./Translations";
import { uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const UserContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [userCredentials, setUserCredentials] = useState(null);
  const [userdbData, setUserdbData] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [resetPassword, setResetPassword] = useState(false);
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("Cameroon");
  const [otpSucceeded, setOtpSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [accountType, setAccountType] = useState("");
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
  // Use invisible reCAPTCHA

  auth.languageCode = language;
  let userDocSnap = undefined;

  const eng = en;
  const fre = fr;

  const modifyLanguage = (chosenLanguage) => {
    setLanguage(chosenLanguage);
    auth.languageCode = language;
    switch (chosenLanguage) {
      case "en":
        setLangPack(eng);
        break;
      case "fr":
        setLangPack(fre);
        break;
      default:
        setLangPack(eng);
    }
  };

  const [langPack, setLangPack] = useState(eng);

  const modifyCountry = (chosenCountry) => {
    setCountry(chosenCountry);
  };

  const generateRecaptcha = () => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      "sign-in-button",
      {
        size: "invisible",
        callback: (response) => { },
      },
      auth
    );
  };

  const requestCode = (phoneNumber) => {
    let appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        console.log("code requested");
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const confirmCode = (otp) => {
    let confirmationResult = window.confirmationResult;
    confirmationResult
      .confirm(otp)
      .then((result) => {
        // User signed in successfully.
        setOtpSucceeded(true);
        setUserCredentials(result);
        setUser(result.user);
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
        // ...
        setOtpSucceeded(false);
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      });
  };

  const createUser = async (displayName, email, password) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        updateProfile(userCredentials.user, {
          displayName: displayName,
        });
        return userCredentials.user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });
  };

  const updateUser = async (displayName, email, password) => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    await updateProfile(user, {
      displayName: displayName,
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Display Name updated to " + displayName);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    await updatePassword(user, password)
      .then(() => {
        reauthenticateWithCredential(auth, userCredentials);
        // signInWithCredential(auth, userCredentials);
        console.log("Password updated to " + password);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    await updateEmail(user, email)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Email updated to " + email);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
        displayName: displayName,
        email: user.email,
        phone: user.phoneNumber,
        accountType: accountType,
        country: country,
        language: language,
        wallet: 0,
        validated: validated,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // update the user's photoURL
  const updatePhotoURL = async (photoURL) => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    await updateProfile(user, {
      photoURL: photoURL,
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Photo URL updated to " + photoURL);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const setNewPassword = (password) => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    updatePassword(user, password)
      .then(() => {
        // signInWithCredential(auth, userCredentials);
        console.log("Password updated to " + password);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  const login = (email, password) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    return signOut(auth);
  };

  const chooseAccountType = (type) => {
    setAccountType(type);
    if (type === "User / Client") {
      setValidated(true);
    } else {
      setValidated(false);
    }
  };

  const getdbUserData = async () => {
    console.log("Beginning to get the user data");
    try {
      const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      userDocSnap = await (await getDoc(userDocRef)).data();

      if (userDocSnap) {
        updateUserData();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const updateUserData = () => {
    setUserdbData(userDocSnap);
  };

  const uploadProfilePicture = async (file, userPhotoURLRef) => {
    console.log("beginning the upload of the User Profile Picture");
    await uploadBytes(userPhotoURLRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("Successfully Uploaded a blob or file!");
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
        console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
        updatePhotoURL(downloadURL);
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
      console.log(currentUser);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getfbData = onAuthStateChanged(auth, () => {
      console.log("Automatically pulling user's data");
      getdbUserData();
    });
    return () => {
      getfbData();
    };
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        createUser,
        otpSucceeded,
        user,
        logout,
        login,
        language,
        modifyLanguage,
        langPack,
        country,
        modifyCountry,
        generateRecaptcha,
        requestCode,
        confirmCode,
        accountType,
        chooseAccountType,
        updateUser,
        updatePhotoURL,
        resetPassword,
        setResetPassword,
        setNewPassword,
        userdbData,
        getdbUserData,
        uploadProfilePicture,
        validated,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AuthContextProvider;

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

```
export default AuthContextProvider;

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

I am at my wit's end... Please I need help.

I tried creating a UserContext to supply data about the login state and account data of my user throughout the application. I used the same context structure that worked with ionic react v6 and it gave me only the errors I shared.

Answer (score 0):

what I suggest is that: move `index.html` from public to beneath `package.json` after that convert the file from

> Js
> To
> JSX